# How do I create a instance of this Method here?

Tags: java, return-value, instance

```
public LeNo generate (PrintStream stream) {

    prepareOperands(stream);
    LeNo l = (LeNo)left;
    LeNo r = (LeNo)right;

    if (l instanceof NumNo && r instanceof NumNo) {
        return new NumNo((Integer.getInteger(l.name()).intValue()*Integer.getInteger(r.name())));
    }
    if ((l instanceof NumNo && l.name().equals("0"))||(r instanceof NumNo && r.name().equals("0"))) {
        return new NumNo(0); // cut of rest of code here....
```

Is there a way I can create a new NumNo method without having to create it when I return?

The thing is I still want to return NumNo, but without creating a new NumNo doing it.

Answer (score 1):

It is just  `return new NumNo(0);` that you don't want to create right?  Because it is the same every time?  If so, you can create a static instance of that object.  For example,
private static final NewNo ZERO = new NewNo(0);

This is called the flyweight pattern, where you create commonly used instances once.

Comment: I think both "new NumNo" are desired to not be created, but in the first instance if there are appropriate setters then the values can be set and "l" or "r" could be returned.

Comment: I want to create return Num(0), but without putting the new there. When I do that, I get an error message saying it can't find the method NumNo. So I guess I have to initialise it before I return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
return NumNo.getClass();
```

To return a class instead of an instance.

Create an instance with `java.lang.Class.newInstance()`

for example:

```
klass = generate(stream);
object = klass.newInstance();
```

Comment: Note newInstance() assumes you have a public non argument constructor.